# How to Terminate a Python bot in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am hosting a Twitter bot on Heroku, which runs `twitterBot.py`, resulting in the bot posting a tweet.

I want the script to terminate (and end the Heroku process) after posting the tweet (to minimise dyno time).

`sys.exit()` doesn't seem to exit the script when running the command in bash on Heroku.

```
    try:
        api.update_status(post_quote)
        print("\nTwitterBot posted successfully")
    except:
        print("\nTwitterBot Error: Failed Posting Message")

    #exit out of the heroku process
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What is the output of `heroku ps` ?

Comment: @dejdej The output from manually running the script is:

`~ $ python twitterBot.py & 
[1] 7
TwitterBot posted successfully
^C
[1]+  Done` Note how I have to press `ctrl + c` to exit out of the Python script.